# How to print a nested list with dictionaries inside to an HTML file?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

With `products` I want to generate automatically these tables:
[image: Tables]

And code for these tables should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <h1>Fun Market</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <thead bgcolor= "red">
            <th>Clean</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Cleanex $ 01.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>to clean</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Toothbrush $ 01.50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>oral hygiene</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table border="1">
        <thead bgcolor= "red">
            <th>Kitchen</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Spaguetti $ 01.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Easy to cook</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rice $ 1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>For all family</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table border="1">
        <thead bgcolor= "red">
            <th>House</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Door $ 25.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>A resistant door</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

What I have done is this:

```
def textFile():
    products = [['Clean', {'number': '42565', 'name': 'Cleanex', 'price': '01.00', 'description': 'to clean'}, {'number': '45217', 'name': 'Toothbrush', 'price': '01.50', 'description': 'oral hygiene'}], 
                ['Kitchen', {'number': '47851', 'name': 'Spaguetti', 'price': '01.00', 'description': 'Easy to cook'}, {'number': '5852', 'name': 'Rice', 'price': '1.00', 'description': 'For all family'}], 
                ['House', {'number': '78595', 'name': 'Door', 'price': '25.00', 'description': 'A resistant door'}]]
    #If it helps, products has the following estructure: [[Category, dictionary1,dictionary2,...],[Category, dictionary1,dictionary2,...],[Category, dictionary1,dictionary2,...],...]
    sending = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <h3>Fun Market</h3>
        <hr>"""
    for number  in products:
        sending = sending + """<h1 >"""+number[0]+""" </h1>"""
        for i in range(1,len(number)):
            sending = sending + """<h3 >"""+number[i]['name']+" $ "+number[i]['price']+"""</h3>"""
            sending = sending + """<h4>"""+number[i]['description']+"""</h4>"""
    for i in range(4):
        sending = sending + """<h1> </h1>"""
        sendingAgain = """    
        </body>
        </html>
            """
        sending = sending + sendingAgain
        text = open("Store.html", "wb")
        text.write(bytes(sending,'utf-8'))
        text.close()
        
textFile()
```

But I get the following:

[image: no tables]

And the problem with that is that it is not into tables, and I would like to get it in tables to then add styles with CSS.
I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: look at template engine like `jinja2`. Also your question states that code for templates should have the style in it (e.g. red background hardcoded for table header) and at the same time you state you want to use css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create the HTML for the tables without using a template.

```
def textFile():
    products = [['Clean', {'number': '42565', 'name': 'Cleanex', 'price': '01.00', 'description': 'to clean'}, {'number': '45217', 'name': 'Toothbrush', 'price': '01.50', 'description': 'oral hygiene'}], 
                ['Kitchen', {'number': '47851', 'name': 'Spaguetti', 'price': '01.00', 'description': 'Easy to cook'}, {'number': '5852', 'name': 'Rice', 'price': '1.00', 'description': 'For all family'}], 
                ['House', {'number': '78595', 'name': 'Door', 'price': '25.00', 'description': 'A resistant door'}]]
    #If it helps, products has the following estructure: [[Category, dictionary1,dictionary2,...],[Category, dictionary1,dictionary2,...],[Category, dictionary1,dictionary2,...],...]
    sending = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <h3>Fun Market</h3>
        <hr>"""
    for number  in products:
      table = f'<table border="1"><thead bgcolor="red"><th>{number[0]}</th></thead>'
      table = table +"<tbody>"
      for i in range(1,len(number)):
        trow = f"<tr><td>{number[i]['name']+' '+number[i]['price']}</td></tr>"
        table += trow
        trow =  f"<tr><td>{number[i]['description']}</td></tr>"
        table += trow
      table += "</tbody></table>"
      sending +=table
    sendingAgain = """    
    </body>
    </html>
        """
    sending = sending + sendingAgain
    text = open("Store.html", "wb")
    text.write(bytes(sending,'utf-8'))
    text.close()
        
textFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

In views.py:

```
    def myMarket(request):

    products = [['Clean', {'number': '42565', 'name': 'Cleanex', 'price': '01.00', 'description': 'to clean'}, {'number': '45217', 'name': 'Toothbrush', 'price': '01.50', 'description': 'oral hygiene'}], 
                ['Kitchen', {'number': '47851', 'name': 'Spaguetti', 'price': '01.00', 'description': 'Easy to cook'}, {'number': '5852', 'name': 'Rice', 'price': '1.00', 'description': 'For all family'}], 
                ['House', {'number': '78595', 'name': 'Door', 'price': '25.00', 'description': 'A resistant door'}]]
    products_header = [i[0] for i in products] # get the first items "Clean, Kitchen, House"
    products_body = [i[1:] for i in products] # get the other items "The dicts"
    products_header_and_body = dict(zip(products_header, products_body)) # Convert them into key pairs

    context = {
        'products': products_header_and_body,
    }
           
    return render(request, 'myMarket.html', context)
```

In HTML template:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <h1>Fun Market</h1>
    <table border="1">
        {% for k,v in products.items %}
        <thead bgcolor= "red">
            <th>{{k}}</th>
        </thead>
        {% for item in v %}
        <tbody>
            {% for s,t in item.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{s}}: <b style="color: blue">{{t}}</b></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}
        
</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

You can do more css styling to the Table in the HTML template. But all you needed to do to iterate through the list is to convert it into key pairs.